# Set CSS 100% height on div

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

I have a div and I've tried to set the height to 100% so the content of it makes the div grow to fit.

I've tried the following and it won't work:

**Adding 100%:**

```
#latest{ height: 100%; background: #e3e3e3 url(banner_grad.jpg) repeat-x; border: none; margin-top: 10px;}
```

**Leaving having to height setting at all, so the div would just fit the content in:**

```
#latest{ background: #e3e3e3 url(banner_grad.jpg) repeat-x; border: none; margin-top: 10px;}
```

Unless I set a specific height (e.g. height: 370px;) the div will not even show it's outline in design view in Dreamweaver. Very odd.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height property will correct here.But instead of this use following code.If you go on adding content the div will also increase in height.

```
#largest {
    background: url("firefox-gray.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #E3E3E3;
    border: medium none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not set heights of divs as percentages, mainly as content tends to make divs grow downwards, so you would be limiting yourself.

Take a look at the min-height css property though. That, I think, will go some way to sorting your problem.

Answer (score 0):

may be you have to write like this:

```
html, body{
 height:100%
}

#latest{ 
height: 100%; 
background: #e3e3e3 url(banner_grad.jpg) repeat-x; 
border: none;
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the content of the div have a "float: left" or a "float: right" attribute?

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body{
   height:100%
}

div{height: 50%}
```

I don't know the browser compatibility of this so you may need to test it.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKZFa/